# C# reflection if: 0 equals 1?

Tags: c#, reflection, if-statement, reflection.emit, system.reflection

I have problem. This is my code:

```
var method = new DynamicMethod("dummy", null, Type.EmptyTypes);
var g = method.GetILGenerator();
g.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));

Label inequality = g.DefineLabel();
Label equality = g.DefineLabel();
Label end = g.DefineLabel();

g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "string");
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "string");
g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(String).GetMethod("op_Equality", new Type[]{typeof(string), typeof(string)}));
g.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[]{typeof(int)}));
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ceq);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, equality);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, inequality);
g.MarkLabel(inequality);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Specified strings are different.");
g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[]{typeof(string)}));
g.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, end);
g.MarkLabel(equality);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Specified strings are same.");
g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));
g.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, end);
g.MarkLabel(end);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var action = (Action)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
action();
```

This is my result:

```
1
Specified strings are different.
```

But why is output wrong? Ceq instruction is comparing 1 as result from op_Equation and 0 which is on the top of stack. And 1 **not equals** 0. So why it is? Where is error? Please help me.

Comment: This is your 3rd question on this topic in the last hour.  Are you spending enough time working out these problems on your own?

Comment: I don't have any book soruces for this. I know that it seems stupid because I'm using same code three times but I need to know answer and I don't know how to solve it. You can close it if you want but it's normal question. I can also delete it and place it here tomorrow....

Comment: It says that they're different; isn't that what you want?

Comment: Is word 'string' different to word 'string'? no or I'm stupid.

Comment: Also both your br_true codes seem to be redircting to the immediately following statement, i.e. not doing anything useful.

Comment: Might you write and compile the method in vanilla c#, and then disassemble it to see what it was supposed to be?

Comment: If you edit the question as we go along fixing it, then nobody turning this up in a week/month/year's time is going to have a clue what's going on. You have two constructive answers below which now contradict each other, though each was correct for the state of the question when they were posted....!!!!

Comment: Kirk Woll - this wants less questions.... .... and from your speech I understand that I need to solve my problem alone or I should create new question... It's interesting here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `g.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, inequality);`, you need to jump to the "equality" statement manually. Else it will execute the next instruction anyway. So you'll need to insert the following line after it:

```
g.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, equality);
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to jump to the label `equality` when it is declared as the next instruction anyway. So remove that.

so the section will look like this:

```
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ceq);

g.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, inequality); // if true goto inequality
g.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, equality); // else goto equality

g.MarkLabel(inequality);            
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Specified strings are different.");
g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[]{typeof(string)}));
g.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, end); // goto end

g.MarkLabel(equality);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Specified strings are same.");
g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));

g.MarkLabel(end);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your branch is to the label "inequality" which immediately follows the statement anyway. So whether you branch or not, this is the code that will be called. You should be branching to the label "equality".

Also, your line `g.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, equality);` is pointless as it will never be reached - you jump over it on the preceding statement. And your "inequality" label will not actually be used anywhere once the logic is fixed, so you may as well ditch that too.